# How to solve Error: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter

I wanted to program a simple graphical version of Tic Tac Toe in Python after having previously made a text based one with a friend. For this I used tkinter. I have been able to get rid of all mistakes in the first window where you choose which symbol you want. But in the second window when you are supposed to place it, when I press one of the buttons it tells me that "pyimage2" doesn't exist which seems to be a common error

I have already checked out some other threads where I was told that I should use TopLevel instead, since there can only be one instance of Tk(). But I already am using it, and when I try using two instances by using destroy() on the first, the error remains. I have also switched from simple PhotoImage to PIL, but even that is of no help

```py
from tkinter import *
from random import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
global root
global SpielerSymbol
SpielerSymbol = "Defaultshit"
def combine_funcs(*funcs):
        def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
            for f in funcs:
                f(*args, **kwargs)
class SelectionScreen:
    def __init__(self,pRoot):
        Imageo = Image.open("o.png")
        o = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Imageo)
        Imagex = Image.open("x.png")
        x = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Imagex)
        Screen = Toplevel(pRoot)
        self.TextField = Label(Screen, text="Please choose a symbol.")
        self.TextField.grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.ButtonX = self.SelectionButton(x,Screen)
        self.ButtonX.Choice.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        self.ButtonO = self.SelectionButton(o,Screen)
        self.ButtonO.Choice.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
        Screen.mainloop()
    class SelectionButton:
        def __init__(self, pImage, pScreen):
            self.Choice = Button(pScreen, image = pImage, command = lambda: combine_funcs(setSpielerSymbol(str(pImage)), pScreen.destroy(), pScreen.quit()))
def setSpielerSymbol(pZeichen):
    global SpielerSymbol
    SpielerSymbol = pZeichen
class Game:
    def __init__(self, pRoot):
        global SpielerSymbol
        ImageFeldx = Image.open("Feldx.png")
        Feldx = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ImageFeldx)
        ImageFeldo = Image.open("Feldo.png")
        Feldo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ImageFeldo)
        ImageFeld = Image.open("Feld.png")
        Feld = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ImageFeld)
        Window = Toplevel(pRoot)
        Feld1 = [self.Feld(Feld,Window,1,1), self.Feld(Feld,Window,1,2), self.Feld(Feld,Window,1,3),
        self.Feld(Feld,Window,2,1), self.Feld(Feld,Window,2,2), self.Feld(Feld,Window,2,3),
        self.Feld(Feld,Window,3,1), self.Feld(Feld,Window,3,2), self.Feld(Feld,Window,3,3)]
        Window.mainloop()
    class Feld:
        def __init__(self, pImage, pWindow, pRow, pColumn):
            self.Feld1 = Button(pWindow, image = pImage, command =lambda: combine_funcs(self.setFeldImage(self), Window.quit()) )
            self.Feld1.grid(row=pRow,column=pColumn)
        def setFeldImage(self, pFeld1):
            pFeld1.Feld1.config(image=SpielerSymbol)
def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    SelectionScreen1 = SelectionScreen(root)
    print("Das ist das Werk von Feiglingen")
    Game1 = Game(root)
main()
```

The output should be two windows, first the one where you choose a symbol, that one should work fine, and the second should be a tic tac toe field where clicking on a button should display the symbol you've chosen. And what I instead get is the error message `image "pyimage1" doesn't exist`
Also sorry for the ugly code, I am still a beginner, especially at Python

Comment: Might be a [PhotoImage collection bug](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm). What happens if you assign your PhotoImages to `self.x` and `self.o` instead of just x and o?

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. There seems to be a new issue regarding window, but I think I might be able to pursue that on my own. Again Thank you very much